# Rails: How can I run redis automatically with `rails s`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I'm working on a project using redis. 
When developing, I need to run `redis-server` and `rails s`, which is quite repetative. Can I set anything up, so everytime I run `rails s`, it would also start `redis-server`?

I'm on `ubuntu 14.04`

or how can I just start `redis` when start ubuntu?

Comment: have a look at foreman gem: https://github.com/ddollar/foreman. Description: http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

create an initializer in config/initializers/redis.rb and add the following:

$redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)

Comment: This will not startup the Redis server, but just connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to start redis server automatically by Ubuntu itself:

```
sudo update-rc.d redis-server enable
```

Comment: Why it tells me `update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/redis-server: file does not exist
`?

Comment: Have you install Redis from repository (using 'apt-get install') or compiled it manually (steps as on http://redis.io/download) ?

Comment: I used the latter, complied it manually. I thought this is recommended by redis?

Comment: It might be recommended by Redis team as you'll receive the most up to date version. In general it's easier to maintain apps installed from repository, you'll receive updates etc. In your case you should either try to add/localize init script or replace compiled version with the one from Ubuntu repository.  Check this out as well: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-redis - maybe "sudo update-rc.d redis_6379 defaults" will do the job for you.